# Is there a way to set Background Color of XAxis

Tags: recharts

I checked the docs and all I could find was to set the stroke but I need the whole xAxis **background** and not only font color.

Comment: Do you mean the color of the line?

Comment: nope I mean after the xAxis(where all values are shown) there is a transparent background, that'w what i am trying to change :P

Comment: I tried using CSS as I don't know a way to directly modify the xAxis background using the Recharts API.

The xAxis background area has a class name of "recharts-cartesian-axis-ticks". (This is the same as yAxis). However it is an SVG element and not a div, so setting the background to that class name does not work for me.

Comment: Perhaps if you already know the dimensions of your graph area, you can hide an absolute div behind your graph with the appropriate background. Obviously this is not an ideal solution.

Comment: @manley13 I did fix it like that with a background size = height - height of xaxis, but now I am asked to build it like a library so ...  workarounds aren't that great 
SUPER THANKS anyway

Comment: would you mind upvoting it? to send it to 0 someone did -1 to it and i dont want to repost

Comment: No prob - upvoted

Comment: You may need to fork recharts to make your own custom variant of their library

Comment: @manley13 do you have any idea where that XAxis background part is implemented (are you familar with forking recharts, or it was only a suggestion)

Comment: Sure, it is in /recharts/es6/cartesian/XAxis.js

Comment: it is somewhat straightforward to read and its only 110 lines pre-minimification

Comment: There is no background component for the xAxis though - that's what you have to make and your purpose in forking it. The only background at the moment is the entire chart.

Answer (score 0):

@Renaldo Balaj Well, you could add an svg element to your chart like here

https://codesandbox.io/s/highlight-zomm-line-chart-forked-o18fe

But there is an issue I am struggling with: on codesandbox on resize all is ok, but in my browser those rectangles are moving out of borders while resizing, can't make them attached to axis

Comment: This is very close to a) a link-only answer (which risks being deleted) b) a description of your own problem (which is not an answer and should be deleted) .  I recommend that you [edit] and try to heed [answer] more obviously. Also, your post gives the impression that you mistake StackOverflow for a discussion forum. Please take the [tour] to understand better about the idea of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```jsx
<XAxis
  dataKey="name"
  tick={{ fill: "red" }}
  stroke="red"
/>
```

You can use a word (e.g., "red" or "blue") or a hex color code (`"#0092a5"`) or a css/scss variable (`var(--color)`).