# Recharts set axis background color

Tags: recharts

I've searched the way to color the background of axis in my chart. Rechart doesn't provide such an option, so we need to find some way to overcome this

There was such a question and I provided the answer

[Is there a way to set Background Color of XAxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59036267/is-there-a-way-to-set-background-color-of-xaxis/70756247#70756247)

Answer can be seen on https://codesandbox.io/s/highlight-zomm-line-chart-forked-o18fe

In codesandbox it is fine in any scale.
But if I apply that code in my browser and resize the window then those rectangles moves outside of the axis. Is there any way to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The fill property can be used to set the axis background color.

```
<CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" fill='red'/>
```

The result can be seen here:

[image: here]

Comment: <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" fill='red'/>